# FetchedResults Controller Filtering On Calculated Value

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview that is managed by an NSFetchedResultsController.

My problem is that i'm trying to filter the data based on a calculated value that requires looking through related values on the core data entity.

To give further context: I've got a core data entity named "Task", and a to-many relationship named "TaskActions".

I'd like to sort the tasks tableview by looking through the actions and using some custom logic.

The problem is that I don't really know how this is best achieved.

**Here is what i've tried** :

```
 NSFetchRequest *requestForAll = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Task"];
 NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskActionPerformed == %@",@YES];
 requestForAll.predicate = actionPredicate;
 [self setFetchedResultsController:[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:requestForAll managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil]];
```

I can get this "Filtering" to sort of work by putting the property "taskActionPerformed" on the entity, and overriding the getter value like so :

```
 - (NSNumber*)taskActionPerformed
{
    for (TaskActions *action in self.actions)
    {
        //Perform Logic
        return @YES;
    } 
    return @NO;
}
```

However, I've read that overriding the KVO methods (like i'm doing with the getter) is discouraged, and even not recommended.

Additionally, the above solution only works until I've persisted my data. After I save my data, taskActionPerformed isn't called and the fetchedresultscontroller doesn't load.

I'd really like to know the best way to solve this general issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to filter in memory.

From the Core Data Programming Gude in [Fetching Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW3)

> You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory yourself). ... To summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should typically not add Objective-C-based predicates or sort descriptors to the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of the fetch.

Comment: I think i have somewhat of an idea how this would be done, but could you give further guidance on how doing this filter "in memory" is to be done? Specifically, how to use the NSFetchedResultsController with an in memory structure (i'm guessing NSArray).

Comment: Right. In most cases you can filter your fetched results controller's `fetchedObjects` on the fly in your `datasource` methods. An `NSArray` is also feasible.